# SP.RequestExecutor on SharePoint online

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I deployed an App SharePoint hosted.
I am using `SP.RequestExecutor` and it is working fine on SharePoint premise. 
but on SharePoint online it is not working. 
I added the library using this: `$.getScript("/_layouts/15/SP.RequestExecutor.js");`
Can I use that library also in SharePoint online?

This is my **CODE** :

```
var createitem = new SP.RequestExecutor("/");
createitem.executeAsync({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/items('" + id + "')/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName='" + file.name + "')",
    method: "POST",
    binaryStringRequestBody: true,
    body: contents2,
    success: function (data) {
        //OK
    },
    error: function (msg) {
        alert("error");
    },
    state: "Update"
});
```

Comment: What error are you receiving when it fails?

Comment: Nothing, I try to access to the msg.body, msg.status but they are undefined

Comment: Where does it fail? The new `SP.RequestExecutor("/");` or the `createitem.executeAsync({...`?

Comment: It fails in the executeAsync, I can see the alert in the error callback.

Comment: I'm looking at a SP hosted app I have working for SPO, and I'm using the app web url to create the `SP.RequestExecutor`.  My REST url is quite different as well: `appweburl + "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Communication%20Log')/items?$select=Title,Date1&$orderby=Date1 desc&$top=5&@target='" + encodeURIComponent(hostweburl) + "'"`  hostweburl being the url for the sharepoint online site, appweburl being the app's url.

Comment: I will try to change it

Comment: Is @target hardcoded?

Comment: I posted an answer with my code.  I hope it helps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/officeapps/archive/2012/11/29/solving-cross-domain-problems-in-apps-for-sharepoint.aspx) when I first created my app.
First, you need both the app web url and the host web url:

```
var hostweburl = decodeURIComponent( getQueryStringParameter("SPHostUrl") );
var appweburl = decodeURIComponent( getQueryStringParameter("SPAppWebUrl") );
```

Then you need to load the `SP.RequestExecutor.JS` file, which I did differently than what was in the link:

```
var scriptbase = hostweburl + "/_layouts/15/";

$.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js",
    function () {
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js",
            function () { $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.RequestExecutor.js", execCrossDomainRequest); }
        );
    }
);
```

`execCrossDomainRequest` is the function in which I executed the cross domain request.  In my function, I was retrieving the five most recent items from a list called "Communication Log":

```
function execCrossDomainRequest() {
    var context;
    var factory;
    var appContextSite;

    context = new SP.ClientContext(appweburl);
    factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appweburl);
    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
    appContextSite = new SP.AppContextSite(context, hostweburl);

    var executor = new SP.RequestExecutor(appweburl);

    executor.executeAsync(
        {
            url:
                appweburl +
                    "/_api/SP.AppContextSite(@target)/web/lists/getbytitle('Communication%20Log')/items?$select=Title,Date1&$orderby=Date1 desc&$top=5&@target='" +
                        encodeURIComponent(hostweburl) + "'",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: successHandler,
            error: errorHandler
        }
    );
}
```

I'm sure you can piece the rest together.  This was done when I was fairly fresh with both SharePoint apps and javascript, so it may be improved.

Comment: Thanks, I changed my url request (added @target).It is working fine on-premise, but it is not working on Online :/

Comment: I created new SP.RequestExecutor("/") but it needs the appweburl parameter. Strange that it was working on-premise. Thanks

Comment: Why in your function you created context, factory and appContextSite instances when you didnt use them anywhere?

Comment: @MichalHainc See the last comment under the code block.  I suppose I ought to update this answer when I have a chance.

Comment: @wjervis Would be helpfull ... Im struggling with this for 2 days, I'd like to use the appContextSite & context objects to work with the JSOM and manipulate data on the hostWeb but all I am getting is Access denied

Comment: Does the app have the appropriate permissions? I'd be able to provide more help later.  Unfortunately I'm at work right now, so I can't provide detailed help right now.

Comment: @wjervis yes, I have sitecollection scope at FullControl

Comment: @wjervis I'd appreciate greatly if you could have a look if you find some free time later... I'm really desparate

Comment: @MichalHainc If you post a question with the troubles you're having, you may get a response quicker.  I'll be able to take a look at it in about an hour, when I go on my lunch break.

Comment: @wjervis no stress... Im slowly starting to find out what is the issue... Angular2 router changes my url to other url than I entered the page with. Then this modified url is beeing used in the Refferer header when making JSOM proxified requests and I think this causes the error. Need to prove it with a blank solution without using the router

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59375/discussion-between-wjervis-and-michal-hainc).